# a BigQuery error stating "Not found: Dataset project:project was not found in location US"

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm encountering an error

> "Not found: Dataset project-3-395116:project-3-395116 was not found in
> location US"

when running the following code:

```
SELECT
  warehouse.warehouse_id,
  CONCAT(warehouse.state, ':', warehouse.warehouse_alias) AS warehouse_name,
  COUNT(orders.order_id) AS number_of_orders,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `project-3-395116.warehouse_orders` AS orders) AS total_orders,
  CASE
    WHEN COUNT(orders.order_id) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `project-3-395116.warehouse_orders.orders` AS Orders) <= 0.20
    THEN "Fulfilled 0-20% of Orders"
    WHEN COUNT(orders.order_id) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `project-3-395116.warehouse_orders.orders` AS Orders) > 0.20
    AND COUNT(orders.order_id) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `project-3-395116.warehouse_orders.orders` AS Orders) <= 0.60
    THEN "Fulfilled 21-60% of Orders"
    ELSE "Fulfilled more than 60% of Orders"
  END AS fulfillment_summary
FROM
  `project-3-395116.warehouse_orders ` AS warehouse
LEFT JOIN
  `project-3-395116.warehouse_orders` AS orders
  ON orders.warehouse_id = warehouse.warehouse_id
GROUP BY
  warehouse.warehouse_id,
  warehouse_name
HAVING
  COUNT(Orders.order_id) > 0;
```

I'm trying to run the above SQL code, but I'm getting an error stating that the dataset

> "project-3-395116:project-3-395116" was not found in the location US.

I have checked the dataset name and location, and they appear to be correct. I'm using BigQuery Sandbox account. My location is in the US.

Additional details to clarify the issue:

1. My project_id name was `project-3-395116`
2. My dataset_id  `warehouse_orders`
3. I had two tables: `orders`  and `warehouse`
4. Query columns to retrieve: `warehouse_id`,  `warehouse_name`, `number_of_orders`, `total_orders` and `fulfillment_summary`

[see the image for the details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mx3T5.png)

I've read similar threads and I am still confused.

Can someone please help me understand why I'm encountering this error and how to resolve it? Thank you for your patience and for taking the time to help.

Comment: looks like you are missing tables names! most likely `orders` and `warehouse`!

Comment: Is the dataset name the same as the GCP project name, project-3-395116? The error is saying that a dataset called project-3-395116 cannot be found within the project-3-395116 project.

The expected syntax is either <project_id>.<dataset_id>.<table_name> OR <dataset_id>.<table_name> (in the second case the project will be inferred from the query project).

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I rewrote the syntax, dropped some things, and added some things.

Comment: @joe, thank you so much for your insight. My query had 3 syntax-related mistakes. I used <project_id>.<dataset_id> and I should have used <dataset_id>.<table_name> twice. And I also used: <project_id>.<dataset_id> instead of using:  <project_id>.<dataset_id>.<table_name>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to thank the following people for their wisdom and insight:

@mikhail-berlyant @joe @jayapal

### I was able to fix it and I will include the full code below:

#### My code had multiple mistakes:

Just in case it’s a little bit confusing I want to provide additional context

1. My project_id name was `project-3-395116`
2. My dataset_id  `warehouse_orders`
3. I had two tables: `orders`  and `warehouse`
4. Query columns to retrieve: `warehouse_id`,  `warehouse_name`, `number_of_orders`, `total_orders` and `fulfillment_summary`

### Mistake 1 :  `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM`

I used: <project_id>.<dataset_id>

I should have used:  <dataset_id>.<table_name>

**Wrong**

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `project-3-395116.warehouse_orders` AS orders) AS total_orders,
```

**Correct**

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `warehouse_orders.orders` AS orders) AS total_orders,
```

### Mistake 2 :  `FROM`

I used: <project_id>.<dataset_id>

I should have used:  <project_id>.<dataset_id>.<table_name>

**Wrong**

```
FROM
  `project-3-395116.warehouse_orders ` AS warehouse
```

**Correct**

```
FROM
  `project-3-395116.warehouse_orders.warehouse` AS warehouse
```

### Mistake 3 :  `LEFT JOIN`

I used: <project_id>.<dataset_id>

I should have used: <dataset_id>.<table_name>

**Wrong**

```
LEFT JOIN
  `project-3-395116.warehouse_orders` AS orders
  ON orders.warehouse_id = warehouse.warehouse_id
```

**Correct**

```
LEFT JOIN
  warehouse_orders.orders AS orders
  ON orders.warehouse_id = warehouse.warehouse_id
```

### Correct query:

```
SELECT
  warehouse.warehouse_id,
  CONCAT(warehouse.state, ':', warehouse.warehouse_alias) AS warehouse_name,
  COUNT(orders.order_id) AS number_of_orders,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `warehouse_orders.orders` AS orders) AS total_orders,
  CASE
    WHEN COUNT(orders.order_id) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `project-3-395116.warehouse_orders.orders` AS Orders) <= 0.20
    THEN "Fulfilled 0-20% of Orders"
    WHEN COUNT(orders.order_id) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `project-3-395116.warehouse_orders.orders` AS Orders) > 0.20
    AND COUNT(orders.order_id) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `project-3-395116.warehouse_orders.orders` AS Orders) <= 0.60
    THEN "Fulfilled 21-60% of Orders"
    ELSE "Fulfilled more than 60% of Orders"
  END AS fulfillment_summary
FROM
  `project-3-395116.warehouse_orders.warehouse` AS warehouse
LEFT JOIN
  warehouse_orders.orders AS orders
  ON orders.warehouse_id = warehouse.warehouse_id
GROUP BY
  warehouse.warehouse_id,
  warehouse_name
HAVING
  COUNT(Orders.order_id) > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it is not clear to me if 'project-3-395116' is project name of dataset.... if it is project name, please read below, if dataset, ignore below answer

```
FROM
`project-3-395116.warehouse_orders ` AS warehouse
```

Since, only 2 values given in FROM clause, Bigquery is considering the 1st value as dataset and 2nd as table name

Allowed formats for from are

```
    <project>.<dataset>.<table>
    <dataset>.<table>
```

Comment: @Jaypal My query had 3 syntax-related mistakes. I used <project_id>.<dataset_id> and I should have used <dataset_id>.<table_name> twice. And I also used: <project_id>.<dataset_id> instead of using: <project_id>.<dataset_id>.